# What is meant by "Browser API" in React js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, browser-api

What is meant by Browser-API in react js? Broswer API in useEffect Hooks?

Comment: what's the context of this question? Did some article or documentation use that term?

Comment: The API of the browser? Impossible to say without any context.

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

Comment: Here is the link for reference.

Answer (score 2):

This means the Browser Javascript API, meaning any Javascript methods that interact with the browser, like finding elements on the page, fetching data, setting cookies etc.

Please see [here for more info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API).

I assume you are talking about [this page](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html)?

```js
// Update the document title using the browser API
document.title = `You clicked ${count} times`;
```

They're not implying you *have to use* the browser APIs, just that in this example they are to set the page title.

Hope that makes it a bit more clear